# CAML query filtering is not working

Tags: 2010, caml-query, caml, query

I've googled that it can be in case when query is not well-formed. But I'm verifying it for several hours and didn't find any mistake. Problem is common: query doesn't filters and returns all data.

I have no idea what is wrong, because I checked this query in Stramit CAML viewer and it worked fine.

```
        private static SPListItemCollection GetItemsForThisUserAndEvent(SPList list)
        {
            const string queryMask = 
@"<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='{0}' LookupId='TRUE' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>{1}</Value>
        <Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='{2}' LookupId='TRUE' />
            <Value Type='User'>{3}</Value>
        <Eq>
    </And>
<Where>";

            var query = string.Format(queryMask, MemberListFieldLookupEventName, SPContext.Current.ListItem.ID,
                                                 MemberListFieldLogin, SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID);
            return list.GetItems(query);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query in your case is a string, which means that you are using the `SPList.GetItems(String[])` overload.

That method accept a list of fields to load, not a query. You should be using one of the overloads that accepts an actual SPQuery object.